# Cursor selection in QTextEdit reporting wrong font weight when selecting left-to-right or bottom-to-top

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qtextcursor

I've built an application in Python that makes heavy use of QTextEdits. It has basic formatting buttons and hotkeys so that the user can change their font to Bold, Italic, and Underline. For the most part, these work well, but I'm experiencing some unexpected behavior that, while it is minor, could cause headaches for the average user.

Let's take bold text as an example. When dragging the mouse in a right-to-left direction over bold text, and your selection ends at the beginning of the bold text, `cursor.charFormat().font().bold()` reports the selection as 'False'.

To illustrate, if I have this text in my QTextEdit:

> I'm a **little** bit foo bar

if I were to drag the mouse right-to-left over the word 'little' to select it, I cannot use the button or hotkey to un-bold that word because QT reports the selection as not being bold.

Dragging the mouse in a left-to-right direction causes no such problem. I would assume that is because of where the cursor actually stops and how QT reports the font attributes of the character prior to the cursor and not the character after.

Now, I've been able to remedy this by programmatically redoing the selection using

```
cursor.setPosition(selection_start, QTextCursor.MoveMode.MoveAnchor)
cursor.setPosition(selection_end, QTextCursor.MoveMode.KeepAnchor)
```

but that seems a little bit hack-y to me, and I'm thinking that there's a better way that I just don't know about.

Here's the function that gets called when using the bold button or the bold hotkey:

```
    def setBold(self):
        component = self.win.focusWidget()

        if isinstance(component, QTextEdit):
            cursor = component.textCursor()

            if cursor.hasSelection():
                selection_start = cursor.selectionStart()
                selection_end = cursor.selectionEnd()
                cursor.setPosition(selection_start, QTextCursor.MoveMode.MoveAnchor)
                cursor.setPosition(selection_end, QTextCursor.MoveMode.KeepAnchor)
                char_format = cursor.charFormat()

                if char_format.font().bold():
                    char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Normal)
                    cursor.mergeCharFormat(char_format)
                else:
                    char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
                    cursor.mergeCharFormat(char_format)

            else:
                font = cursor.charFormat().font()

                if font.weight() == QFont.Normal:
                    font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
                    component.setCurrentFont(font)
                else:
                    font.setWeight(QFont.Normal)
                    component.setCurrentFont(font)
```

By the way, it's only the `if cursor.hasSelection()` block that is giving me the troubles. I'd sure appreciate your thoughts on this!

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing: you first report a behavior that happens "if I were to drag the mouse right-to-left", then you say the opposite about "Dragging the mouse in a right-to-left direction". Note that the QTextCursor interface always considers the text format on the *left* of the cursor.

Comment: Shoot, sorry...that was a typo. It's corrected now. But that confirms my suspicion that it always looks to the left of the cursor. Thanks! I'm just looking to emulate behavior that one would expect from using programs like Word and Libre Office. Hopefully my solution is right or someone can offer a better one.

Comment: I know that the default behavior might seem a bit strange, but it's done for convenience and practicality: Qt provides a basic behavior that should be as *fast* as possible, then you could always override the default behavior, but remember that a selection could include lots of different formats. Also note that QTextEdit already provides functions for basic formatting, so you could just call [`setFontWeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setFontWeight) which automatically works on the current text cursor (with or without selection).